# docker-compose up didn't finish npm install.

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker-compose and I'd like to use it for my current development.

after I ran `docker-compose up -d` everything was starting ok and it looks good. But my nodejs application wasn't installed correctly. It seems like `npm install` wasn't complete and I had to do `docker exec -it api bash` to run `npm i` manually inside the container.

Here's my docker-compose.

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: sparrow-api-1
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - $HOME/.aws:/root/.aws
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    environment:
      - SPARROW_EVENT_QUEUE_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      - REDIS_URL=redis
      - NSOLID_APPNAME=sparrow-api
      - NSOLID_HUB=registry:4001
      - NODE_ENV=local
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - NODE_PORT=8081
      - SOCKET_PORT=8002
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=elasticsearch
      - STDIN_OPEN=${STDIN_OPEN}
    networks:
     - default
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
      - elasticsearch
    expose:
      - "8081"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    command: bash docker-command.sh


  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:3.0.7-alpine
    networks:
     - default
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  rabbitmq:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.2-management
    networks:
     - default
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:1.5.2
    networks:
     - default
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"

  registry:
    image: nodesource/nsolid-registry
    container_name: registry
    networks:
     - default
    ports:
      - 4001:4001

  proxy:
    image: nodesource/nsolid-hub
    container_name: hub
    networks:
     - default
    environment:
      - REGISTRY=registry:4001
      - NODE_DEBUG=nsolid

  console:
    image: nodesource/nsolid-console
    container_name: console
    networks:
     - default
    environment:
      - NODE_DEBUG=nsolid
      - NSOLID_APPNAME=console
      - NSOLID_HUB=registry:4001
    command: --hub hub:9000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

# don't forget to create network as well
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Here's my docker-command.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# link the node modules to the root directory of our app, if not exists
modules_link="/usr/src/app/node_modules"
if [ ! -d "${modules_link}" ]; then
  ln -s /usr/lib/app/node_modules ${modules_link}
fi

if [ -n "$STDIN_OPEN" ]; then
  # if we want to be interactive with our app container, it needs to run in
  # the background
  tail -f /dev/null
else
  nodemon
fi
```

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nodesource/nsolid:latest

RUN mkdir /usr/lib/app

WORKDIR /usr/lib/app

COPY [".npmrc", "package.json", "/usr/lib/app/"]

RUN npm install \
  && npm install -g mocha \
  && npm install -g nodemon \
  && rm -rf package.json .npmrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you are running `npm install` without any arguments first:

```
RUN npm install \
  && npm install -g mocha \
```

This will cause a non-zero exit code and due to the `&&` the following commands are not executed. This should also fail the build though, so I'm guessing you already had a working image and added the npm instructions later. To rebuild the image use `docker-compose build` or simply `docker-compose up --build`. Per default `docker-compose up` will only build the image if it did not exist yet.

Comment: So did you mean that every time I just have to run docker-compose up --build instead of just docker-compose up?

Comment: Well that's up to you. If you want to rebuild the image on every run then yes, usually you would only rebuild if you actually changed stuff in the image though.